# Editing Java files outside of project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have to write some little programs in Java for school, so I don't want all that stuff that Eclipse generates with a new project. The way I'm doing it now is this:

1. `$ touch myprog.java`
2. open and edit myprog.java in Eclipse
3. `$ javac myprog.java`
4. `$ java MyProgClass`

The problem is that Eclipse doesn't show warnings and errors while typing the code. It would also be nice if it would let me compile and run the file inside Eclipse (by doing what I do above in the working directory).

Is there any way I can make Eclipse do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is because Eclipse doesn't consider your .java file as something it should compile (and thus generate errors for)

You need to mark the folder containing `myprog.java` as a source folder. Here's how you do it:

Right-click on the folder and choose "Build Path" -> "Use as source folder".

Answer (score 1):

Well because now it's just a text file for eclipse and it isn't linked to java project.

Create new project and put myprog.java to /src folder in eclipse project.

Then:

```
$ javac workspace/yourpoject/src/myprog.java
$ java workspace/yourproject/bin/myprog
```

As a result copy only those 2 files and ignore the rest of project files if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use an existing project into which to create school classes?
Alternatively the NetBeans IDE is somewhat slimmer. You would use Run File there.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: no, you can't make eclipse do that.

Eclipse JDT needs to know the classpath to compile (even if that classpath only includes the JRE), builders to tell you if there are errors, and the search engine for standard IDE things like content assist or open declaration.

It's trivial to create one java project, and then use that to create all of your little java programs.  They compile correctly, report errors, and are easy to run ... and if you want to run them from the command line as well, there's nothing stopping you.